# Google play sign in (Games) - not working in production

Tags: android, google-play-games

I uploaded a new version of my game, where I added google play games integration

All works fine when I run the game in:

- debug mode
- release mode (build an apk with the release credentials)

However, when I publish the game to play store, it isn't working.

Here's the sign in code:

```
 val intent = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
 startActivityForResult(intent.signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
```

The intent opens the sign in activity ("Connecting to play games" at the top), but immediately get closed, calling to my onActivityResult method.

I added a Toast to onActivityResult so I'll be able to see the error:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
{
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
   val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
   Toast.makeText(this, result?.status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

The Toast shows "Status{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=null}"

I don't get it, I just called to **sign in** intent. How come the resolution is **SIGN_IN_REQUIRED**?

Things I did:

- I Created a game in Game Services section (Google play console) and connected it to my app (game), and published it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

- I Added the release keystore's SHA-1 to **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** section in Google API console
- Connected the game in Firebase console

I really don't know what else to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is published, it is signed with the key SHA-1 generated by google and the same key you have to set in your OAuth2 settings.

Comment: What do you mean by 'generated by google'? I added my release keystore's SHA-1 to the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs section in Google API console

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I added the release (upload) keystore instead of the auto generated one by google. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have just been battling with the same issue. You need to check the following :

- Is your apk signed with the same SHA-1 as you have an oauth client id for? Do you need to add an additional oauth client id?
- Is your google account for testing added to the test account list in the play services?
- Have you opted for play store signing, if so, is the SHA-1 in the oauth client id?

Comment: How's test account related to the fact that it isn't working in production?

Comment: You stated that you uploaded to the internal testing section of the play store : "However, when I upload my game to play store (Internal test), it isn't working."

Comment: It is not working when I publish it to production either